# Proof verification: If $a_n\to L$ and $r<L$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$, $a_n> r$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

**Exercise.**

> Prove that if $a_n\to L$ and $r<L$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$, $a_n>r$.

**Attempt.**

Suppose not. Then for all $n_0\in \bf N$, we have that there exists an $n\ge n_0$ such that  $a_n\le r < L$.

Set $\epsilon=L-r>0$, by hypothesis we know that there exists an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we have that

$$
r=L-\epsilon<a_n \tag 1
$$

But by hypothesis we know there's an $n'\ge N$ such that $a_{n'}\le r$, contradicting $(1)$.

E: Provided new version of the proof per Jack's answer.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Not quite: this is not "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but "for infinitely many" (ie., you didn't negate the statement "$\exists n_0 \text{ such that } \forall n \geq n_0,\ a_n > r$" correctly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct. Instead of $n\in \mathbb N$ the argument should start with $\forall n_0\in\mathbb N\;\exists n>n_0:a_n\le r$.

Edit: The new proof is correct.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't that the same? I mean, if there exists an $n$ for $n_0=0$, the same $n$ should work for all the other $n_0$s right?

Comment: Not really. You're saying $a_n\le r$ holds for all $n$. I'm saying it holds for some $n$(albeit an infinite number of $n$'s but still not for all $n$). $\exists$ doesn't mean $\forall$. For example consider $a_{2^n}=1$ and $a_k=0$ if $k\neq 2^n$. $a_k\neq0$ doesn't hold for all $n$ or for all $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$ but for each $n_0\exists n>n_0: a_n\neq0$.

Comment: I see,  I get the difference, but I don't see how the non-equivalence of the formulas affect my argument, maybe an example of when one works and the other doesn't would suffice. Hah! You posted an example when I was writing this haha.

Comment: Ohhh right, of course! Thanks Jack. One last thing, is there any mechanical procedure to negate these complex propositions, so I don't run into this trouble again?

Comment: [There definitely are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) but I haven't studied them. I usually go with the flow :) You'll get the hang of it eventually.

Comment: Yeap, I studied prop. calculus, but when first order formulas are in the mix (with all the nasty quantifiers) I get lost sometimes. I hope I do! Thanks again.

Comment: I forgot this was a proof verification, haha. I've updated the new proof. Could you give it a look?